# PostgreSQL: search using xpath by two keys

Tags: postgresql, xpath

I have a table with the following XML field:

```
<assignments>
<assignment>
    <project_id>6512779208625374885</project_id>
    <start_date>2018-02-05T14:30:06+00:00</start_date>
    <state_id>1</state_id>
</assignment>
<assignment>
    <project_id>7512979208625374996</project_id>
    <start_date>2017-12-01T15:30:00+00:00</start_date>
    <state_id>0</state_id>
</assignment>
<assignment>
    <project_id>5522979707625370402</project_id>
    <start_date>2017-12-15T10:00:00+00:00</start_date>
    <state_id>1</state_id>
</assignment>
</assignments>
```

And I am able to search records by specific project_id:

```
WHERE xpath('/assignments/assignment/project_id/text()', t.assignments)::text[] @> array['6434489631431865709']
```

But I cannot find out how to search for a specific project_id and state_id **for that project** at the same time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really specify what it is you're trying to do exactly, but you can bake the two checks right into the [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Functions_and_operators) expression: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eu-aKLQi)

```sql
select * from test t 
where (xpath('/assignments/assignment/project_id/text()=''7512979208625374996'' and '||
             '/assignments/assignment/state_id/text()=''0'' ', t.assignments)::text[]::bool[])[1]
```

You can also "unpack" the xml with [`xmltable()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING-XMLTABLE) and process it as a table:

```sql
SELECT * from test t,
xmltable('//assignments/assignment'
         passing t.assignments
         columns project_id text, state_id smallint )
where project_id='7512979208625374996' and state_id=0;
```

In [xml2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xml2.html#XML2-XPATH-TABLE) these can be done with [`xpath_bool()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/xml2.html#XML2-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

```sql
select * from test t
where xpath_bool(t.assignments::text,
                  '/assignments/assignment/project_id/text()=''7512979208625374996'' and '||
                  '/assignments/assignment/state_id/text()=''0'' ');
```

and [`xpath_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xml2.html#XML2-XPATH-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT * from
xpath_table('id',
            'assignments',
            'test',
            '/assignments/assignment/project_id|/assignments/assignment/state_id',
            'true'--'project_id = ''6512779208625374885'' '
  )
AS t(id integer, project_id text, state_id smallint)
where project_id='7512979208625374996' and state_id=0;
```

The *key column* (`id`) lets you join it back to your table.

Comment: Thanks. Your first example is not exactly what I need, but I played with it for a while, and found out that what I actually need is:
WHERE xpath_exists('/assignments/assignment[project_id/text()=''6434489631431865709''][state_id/text()=''1'']', t.assignments)
The next problem is how to create an index for such kind of queries, I have not idea yet.

Comment: Sure, that works too. As to the indexing, there's no xml-specific operator family, so no index either. Closest you can get is an [index on the xpath expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html). You could also consider switching to json - jsonpath offers similar or higher flexibility, but there's more functions and operators to choose from, plus indexing on top of all that.